# Building Debian-based docker images without port 80 egress

Tags: docker, debian, apt, debian-buster

I'm trying to set up a continuous build of a Docker image based off `python:3.8-slim-buster`. Unfortunately the build environment does not allow unencrypted HTTP requests out to the Internet. Outbound access to port 443 is allowed. So the default repos in `/etc/apt/sources.list` are inaccessible.

I am aware of [why apt does not use HTTPS](https://whydoesaptnotusehttps.com/). But the obvious answer, "deliver management a lecture on best firewall practices", is not going to work in this particular situation.

I tried globally replacing http with https in the default sources.list, and that works for every repo except `security.debian.org`.

Is there a secure, elegant way to change sources.list within a Docker build to be all HTTPS sources?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you mostly have a solution. What was the issue with `security.debian.org`?

Comment: [security.debian.org does not serve HTTPS.](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/6pgazb/why_is_securitydebianorg_not_available_via_tls/)